# Why does my JRadioButton not work in this case?

Tags: java, swing, components, jradiobutton, itemlistener

I'm trying to create a screen to change the options of  my game, so I'd a problem that using a JRadioButton works in a case and not in the other, and I didn't understand why... Does anybody know what happened?

```
package com.damas.screen;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;


public class Options {

    private JFrame frame;
    protected com.damas.entidades.Options opcoes;
    private JRadioButton radioPlayersNo;
    private JRadioButton radioPlayersYes;
    private JRadioButton radioSoundYes;
    private JRadioButton radioSoundNo;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {


            public void run() {
                try {
                    Options window = new Options();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Options() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        opcoes = new com.damas.entidades.Options();
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 280, 180);
        frame.setResizable(Boolean.FALSE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        radioPlayersYes =new JRadioButton("Yes");
        radioPlayersNo = new JRadioButton("No");
        radioSoundYes = new JRadioButton("Yes");
        radioSoundNo = new JRadioButton("No");
        JLabel labelSound = new JLabel("Sound");
        labelSound.setBounds(50, 99, 86, 23);

        radioPlayersYes.setBounds(129, 39, 55, 14);
        radioPlayersNo.setBounds(190, 30, 55, 32);

        /* Setting default options*/
        radioSoundYes.setSelected(opcoes.getSound());
        radioPlayersYes.setSelected(opcoes.getTwoPlayers());


        /* Setting labels*/
        JLabel lblPlayers = new JLabel("Two Players");
        lblPlayers.setBounds(50, 43, 73, 14);


        JLabel lblColor = new JLabel("Color");
        lblColor.setBounds(50, 74, 46, 14);


        JLabel lblOptions = new JLabel("Options");

        lblOptions.setFont(new Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblOptions.setBounds(109, 11, 46, 14);

        /* Setting radios*/

        JRadioButton radioColorBlack = new JRadioButton("Black");
        radioColorBlack.setBounds(115, 65, 77, 32);


        JRadioButton radioColorWhite = new JRadioButton("White");
        radioColorWhite.setBounds(194, 70, 61, 23);



        JRadioButton radioSoundYes = new JRadioButton("Yes");
        radioSoundYes.setBounds(120, 94, 55, 32);


        JRadioButton radioSoundNo = new JRadioButton("No");
        radioSoundNo.setBounds(194, 99, 61, 23);

        addItemListeners();
        frame.getContentPane().add(radioPlayersYes);
        frame.getContentPane().add(radioPlayersNo);
        frame.getContentPane().add(radioSoundYes);
        frame.getContentPane().add(radioSoundNo);
        frame.getContentPane().add(labelSound);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPlayers);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblColor);
        frame.getContentPane().add(radioColorBlack);
        frame.getContentPane().add(radioColorWhite);

        frame.getContentPane().add(lblOptions);

    }

    private void addItemListeners(){

    radioPlayersYes.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {


            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if(e.getStateChange() == 1){
                    opcoes.setTwoPlayers(Boolean.TRUE);
                    radioPlayersNo.setSelected(Boolean.FALSE);
                }else{
                    opcoes.setTwoPlayers(Boolean.FALSE);
                    radioPlayersNo.setSelected(Boolean.TRUE);
                }
            }
        });



        radioPlayersNo.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if(e.getStateChange() == 1){
                    opcoes.setTwoPlayers(Boolean.FALSE);
                    System.out.println(opcoes.getTwoPlayers());
                    radioPlayersNo.setSelected(Boolean.TRUE);
                    radioPlayersYes.setSelected(Boolean.FALSE);
                }else{
                    opcoes.setTwoPlayers(Boolean.TRUE);
                    System.out.println(opcoes.getTwoPlayers());
                    radioPlayersNo.setSelected(Boolean.FALSE);
                    radioPlayersYes.setSelected(Boolean.TRUE);
                }

            }

        });


        radioSoundYes.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    radioSoundYes.setEnabled(Boolean.TRUE);
                    System.out.println("Radio Sound Yes: Enabled");
                    radioSoundNo.setEnabled(Boolean.FALSE);
                }else{
                    radioSoundYes.setEnabled(Boolean.FALSE);
                    System.out.println("Radio Sound Yes: Disabled");
                    radioSoundNo.setEnabled(Boolean.TRUE);
                }

            }

        });


        radioSoundNo.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    radioSoundNo.setEnabled(Boolean.TRUE);
                    radioSoundYes.setEnabled(Boolean.FALSE);

                }else{
                    radioSoundNo.setEnabled(Boolean.FALSE);
                    radioSoundYes.setEnabled(Boolean.TRUE);
                }

            }

        });

    }


}
```

Comment: I guess you have to read about [ButtonGroup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html) and look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770944/how-to-add-a-radio-button-group-in-a-core-java-program-such-that-only-one-radio)

Answer (score 2):

Group the radio buttons like

```
ButtonGroup playOptionsButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
playOptionsButtonGroup.add(radioPlayersNo);
playOptionsButtonGroup.add(radioPlayersYes);
playOptionsButtonGroup.add(radioSoundYes);
playOptionsButtonGroup.add(radioSoundNo);
```